# Tensorflow : How to perform an operation parallel on every n elements?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

What should I do if I want to get the sum of every 3 elements?

```
test_arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

It sounds like a map function

```
map_fn(arr, parallel_iterations = True, lambda a,b,c : a+b+c)
```

and the result of `map_fn(test_arr)` should be

```
[6,9,12,15,18,21]
```

which equals to

```
[(1+2+3),(2+3+4),(3+4+5),(4+5+6),(5+6+7),(6+7+8)]
```

---

I have worked out a solution after reviewing the official docs: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/map_fn

```
import tensorflow as tf

def tf_map_elements_every(n, tf_op, input, dtype):
    if n >= input.shape[0]:
        return tf_op(input)
    else:
        return tf.map_fn(
            lambda params: tf_op(params),
            [input[i:i-n+1] if i !=n-1 else input[i:] for i in range(n)], 
            dtype=dtype
        )
```

Test

```
t = tf.constant([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
op = tf_map_elements_every(3, tf.reduce_sum, t, tf.int32)

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(op)
```

`[Out]: array([ 6,  9, 12, 15, 18, 21])`

Comment: Why the extra tags?  This uses neither NumPy nor Tensorflow.

Comment: It is better if we can map parallel iterations by using tensorflow's api

Comment: The please update your question to reflect your needs.
Give an example of your *actual* attempt, rather than the Python-only toy solution.

Answer (score 1):

It's even easier: use a list comprehension.
Slice the list into 3-element segments and take the sum of each.
Wrap those in a list.

```
[sum(test_arr[i-2:i+1]) 
    for i in range(2, len(test_arr))]
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply loop through your array until you are 3 from the end.

```
# Takes a collection as argument
def map_function(array):
    # Initialise results and i
    results = []
    int i = 0

    # While i is less than 3 positions away from the end of the array
    while(i <= (len(array) - 3)):
        # Add the sum of the next 3 elements in results
        results.append(array[i] + array[i + 1] + array[i + 2]

        # Increment i
        i += 1

    # Return the array
    return results
```

Comment: So, answer not valid?